# scala memory leak using whilte(true)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, memory, memory-leaks

```
var manager2 = new ClusterTransportManager(result_config)
manager2.start
var producer = new MessageProducer(manager2)
producer.start
var message=new MyMessageListener(batchsize,producer,result_topic,redis)
var consumerConfig: ConsumerConfig = new ConsumerConfig
var manager = new ClusterTransportManager(config)
messageConsumer = new MessageConsumer(consumerConfig, manager, null)
println("start consumer .....")
messageConsumer.start
while (true) {
  messageConsumer.pull(topic, message)
}
```

-------The above is my main function.
That's what I wrote in the scala language, calling the mq's java interface (both for production and consumption), continually eliminating interest consumption from the MQ pull and returning the result to another topic through while (true) {pull (topic, MyMessageListener)}. I monitored stack memory, and memory increased.

[As shown here, I use tools to monitor memory for three days.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc2iv.png)，but I didn't use the StructField class and method.Very puzzled~~And no specific reason for memory leak is found.

> Blockquote

Comment: Why do you think this application is leaking? The fact you see allocated `byte[]` is in no indication of such a thing. It might be that your process has enough memory for GC not to kick in yet. Is your application crashing?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Because I deployed on the docker (4CPU, 4G) and then submitted the jar through spark-submit, it turned out that the container memory was slowly rising every day, about 10 days full.